# How to measure time from adb shell with milliseconds resolution?

Tags: android, shell, adb, mksh

How can I measure time from adb shell with milliseconds or nanoseconds resolution?

Using`date +%.%N` from adb shell returns `1401546811.N` (seconds resolution) instead of something like `1401547289.231869798` (nanoseconds resolution).

How can I get either milliseconds or nanoseconds resolution from adb shell?

Is there some terminal program that I can use to give me this?
I am able to measure time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` from Android application code itself, but I also need something from within `adb shell`.

Comment: just log the events you want to measure and then parse the log

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/sh.htm) (the standard Android *shell* since version 4.0) has a built-in [`EPOCHREALTIME`](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/sh.htm) environment variable:

> Time since the epoch, as returned by `gettimeofday(2)`, formatted as decimal *tv_sec* followed by a dot `.` and *tv_usec* padded to exactly six decimal digits.

So the command to get `epoch` time with *microsecond* accuracy in Windows would be:

```
adb shell echo $EPOCHREALTIME
```

or in Linux:

```
adb shell 'echo $EPOCHREALTIME'
```

If you just need millisecond accuracy:

```
adb shell 'echo ${EPOCHREALTIME:0:14}'
```

Or just the milliseconds part to use with another time format:

```
adb shell 'echo $(date +%T)${EPOCHREALTIME:10:4}'
```

Comment: why I have no `EPOCHREALTIME` var? which version do I need? I'm using android 4.0.4. Your command echos only text `$EPOCHREALTIME`

Comment: Note, if you are on Linux, the SINGLE quotes are very important, otherwise you will get a blank.  If you leave them out, your Linux machine will try to expand the $EPOCHREALTIME and it will likely be blank, so adb shell will faithfully echo ""

You could also do adb shell "echo \$EPOCHREALTIME" where the escaping of the variable is a bit more explicit

Answer (score 0):

Kind of solved my problem by using botbrew. Probably not idea, but at least it works for now.
`/data/botbrew-basil/init -- date +%s.%N` -- returns nanosecond resolution.

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell echo $EPOCHREALTIME` gives you the time with micro seconds,
(don't write it with '\' before the variable name)