# ADB shell command does not work (for Nanosecond timestamp)

Tags: android, shell, adb

I wanted to my current Ping timestamps to include milliseconds, and as it was hard, I am using nanoseconds granularity instead.

```
ping 192.168.47.1 | while read pong; do echo " $pong  @$(date '+%T:%N')"; done
```

It runs on my Ubuntu 12.04, but not on the Nexus 5's ADB shell. Can someone help with that? In general, I need ms as opposed to ns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24070423/1778421

Comment: Thanks! That is a proper solve I guess.